# Where would I use function annotations with google closure?

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure

> The Closure Compiler can use data type information about JavaScript variables to provide enhanced optimization and warnings.

I was looking at [their type expressions](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html#types) and see several listings for function types. Example:

```
{function(string, boolean)}
A function that takes two parameters (a string and a boolean), and has an unknown return value.
```

Another example:

```
{function(new:goog.ui.Menu, string)}
A function that takes one parameter (a string), and creates a new instance of goog.ui.Menu when called with the 'new' keyword.
```

Could someone tell me where I would use these annotations and give an example of what it would look like in practice? Are they primarily for @param and @return for functions that take functions as parameters or return functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any place you would use types:

- var declarations
- parameter types
- return types
- casts

Generally, the Closure Library is a good place to look for examples:

http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js

But here are some samples:

Normal function:

```
/** 
 * @param {string} a 
 * @return {string}
 */
function f(a) {
  return a;
}
```

A function taking general function:

```
/** 
 * @param {Function} a 
 * @return {void}
 */
function f(a) {
}
```

A function taking a function with a single parameter that must be a string and returning a string:

```
/** 
 * @param {function(string):string} a 
 * @return {void}
 */
function f(a) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was thinking this was also necessary or for use when commenting the functions themselves.